# If $-\log n - x + \log u_n +\frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi +\frac{u_n^2}{2} \to 0$, then $\frac{u_n^2}{2\log n} \to 1$ (Extreme Value Theory)

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

I have a question about a line from proof in the textbook EXTREMES AND RELATED PROPERTIES OF RANDOM SEQUENCES AND PROCESSES by Leadbetter. The part of the proof that contains the line can be seen below.

[image]

$\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution, and $\phi$ is the pdf of the standard normal distribution, and I believe $a_n \sim b_n$ denotes that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \to 1$.

From the proof, $u_n$ is an increasing sequence, and $x$ is a fixed number ($u_n$ is chosen so that $1-\Phi(u_n) = \frac{1}{n} e^{-x}$)

I have problem understanding how from $-\log n -x + \log u_n + \frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi + \frac{u_n^2}{2} \to 0$, it follows immediately that $\frac{u_n^2}{2 \log n} \to 1$.

I'd guess $\frac{u_n^2}{2} \sim x+ \log n - \log u_n -\frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi$, but with no way of knowing the limit $\frac{\log u_n}{\log n}$, I do not see any way forward.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: @Shaun all relevant information is written out

Comment: Nevertheless, you shouldn't have pictures of text; they're not user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$-\log n+\log u_n+\frac{u_n^2}2\to c$$
(where $c=x-\frac12\log(2\pi)$), we first derive that $\log u_n+\frac{u_n^2}2$ tends to $+\infty,$ hence so does $u_n.$ Then, dividing by $\log n$ and rearranging the terms, we obtain
$$\frac{u_n^2}{2\log n}\left(1+\frac{2\log u_n}{u_n^2}\right)\to1.$$
Since $\frac{2\log u_n}{u_n^2}\to0,$ we conclude:
$$\frac{u_n^2}{2\log n}\to1.$$